# recreate virtualbox machine with snapshots

Tags: virtualbox

I have (had) a virtual machine, I still have the base image and snapshots, but the `.vbox` file seems to be corrupted.

It is telling me that it is inaccessible. When I look inside the `.vbox` (shown at bottom)  file I see that there is nolonger any mention of the snapshots. It was also telling me that there was an error in line 9 (of `.vbox file`)

I was thinking of recreating the machine from the disk image. I can do this from the base image, using the new machine wizard, by attaching an existing disk. However I do not know how to attach the disk snapshots.

Can you tell me how to attach a disk and its snapshots to a machine?

When I select a snapshot (with the hope that it knows who its parents are, and therefore will attach the whole chain), I get error: *uuid-of-parent-snapshot* of the medium *file-name-I-tried-to-attach* is not found in the media registry /home/richard/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.15-linux">
  <Machine uuid="{5dd89e49-2e41-4f40-a034-ff8b0ca1a230}" name="win7" OSType="Windows7" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2017-06-28T21:19:49Z">
    <Description>Legacy support &#x2014; Microsoft windows</Description>
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{e837b0b1-5453-4dec-9662-42cdc7afbe81}" location="win7 Clone.vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal">
          <HardDisk uuid="{496d0935-0b19-4603-980b-d20f13a0a0ec}" location="Snapshots/{496d0935-0b19-4603-980b-d20f13a0a0ec}.vdi" format="VDI"/>
        </HardDisk>
      </HardDisks>
      <DVDImages>
        <Image uuid="{6352eeaa-3967-4db7-8901-60e6e44e61d8}" location="/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso"/>
        <Image uuid="{888131a2-d809-4259-9d70-5af03730ff07}" location="/home/richard/Downloads/OfficeProfessionalPlus_x86_en-us.iso"/>
        <Image uuid="{d1114527-c7b4-477d-a17f-4d094b170913}" location="/home/richard/Downloads/ms/OfficeProfessionalPlus_x86_en-us.iso"/>
      </DVDImages>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/InfoDlgState" value="400,450,normal"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/InformationWindowGeometry" value="1987,457,600,450"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="Shutdown"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="1280,699"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint1" value="1920,1010"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="2040,39,640,480,max"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition1" value="0,23,1920,1053"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastVisibilityStatusForGuestScreen1" value="true"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastWindowPostion" value="0,0,0,0,max"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastWindowPostion1" value="0,0,0,0,max"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/MiniToolBarAlignment" value="Top"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeDevicesMenuActions" value="FloppyDevices,SharedClipboard,DragAndDrop"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeHelpMenuActions" value="Oracle"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeMachineMenuActions" value="Reset,PowerOff"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeViewMenuActions" value="Scale,VRDEServer,MenuBar,StatusBar,ScaleFactor,Resize"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/SaveMountedAtRuntime" value="yes"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/ScaleFactor" value="1"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/Seamless" value="true"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/StatusBar/IndicatorOrder" value="HardDisks,OpticalDisks,FloppyDisks,Network,USB,SharedFolders,Display,VideoCapture,Features,Mouse,Keyboard"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/VirtualScreenToHostScreen0" value="0"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/VirtualScreenToHostScreen1" value="0"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" value="0"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" value="0"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Snapshot uuid="{87d4c17a-119a-441d-8bc8-544c6f4348f9}" name="base-system" timeStamp="2017-04-08T16:40:24Z">
      <Description>no defrag, trim
</Description>
      <Hardware>
        <CPU count="2">
          <PAE enabled="true"/>
          <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
        </CPU>
        <Memory RAMSize="2048"/>
        <Paravirt provider="HyperV"/>
        <Boot>
          <Order position="1" device="HardDisk"/>
          <Order position="2" device="None"/>
          <Order position="3" device="None"/>
          <Order position="4" device="None"/>
        </Boot>
        <Display VRAMSize="69" monitorCount="2" accelerate2DVideo="true"/>
        <VideoCapture screens="18446744073709551613" rate="307" fps="15"/>
        <RemoteDisplay enabled="false" authType="External" allowMultiConnection="true">
          <VRDEProperties>
            <Property name="TCP/Ports" value="3389"/>
            <Property name="VideoChannel/Enabled" value="false"/>
            <Property name="VideoChannel/Quality" value="75"/>
          </VRDEProperties>
        </RemoteDisplay>
        <BIOS>
          <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
        </BIOS>
        <USB>
          <Controllers>
            <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
          </Controllers>
          <DeviceFilters>
            <DeviceFilter name="Verbatim STORE N GO [0101]" active="false" vendorId="18a5" productId="0302" revision="0101" manufacturer="Verbatim" product="STORE N GO" serialNumber="6481519A" remote="0"/>
          </DeviceFilters>
        </USB>
        <Network>
          <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027A6701C" cable="true" type="82540EM">
            <DisabledModes>
              <InternalNetwork name="intnet"/>
              <NATNetwork name="NatNetwork"/>
            </DisabledModes>
            <NAT/>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="1" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027F3B7E9" type="82540EM">
            <DisabledModes>
              <BridgedInterface name="wlan1"/>
              <InternalNetwork name="intnet"/>
              <HostOnlyInterface name="vboxnet0"/>
              <NATNetwork name="NatNetwork"/>
            </DisabledModes>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="2" MACAddress="080027AB42B9" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="3" MACAddress="0800271F7F6F" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="4" MACAddress="0800272A431D" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="5" MACAddress="080027FF958C" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="6" MACAddress="080027639CFE" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
          <Adapter slot="7" MACAddress="0800276E87FC" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        </Network>
        <LPT>
          <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="7"/>
        </LPT>
        <AudioAdapter controller="HDA" driver="ALSA" enabled="false"/>
        <SharedFolders>
          <SharedFolder name="Downloads" hostPath="/home/richard/Downloads" writable="false" autoMount="true"/>
          <SharedFolder name="win7-readonly" hostPath="/home/richard/+Files/VM/win7-readonly" writable="false" autoMount="true"/>
          <SharedFolder name="win7-share" hostPath="/home/richard/+Files/VM/win7-share" writable="true" autoMount="true"/>
          <SharedFolder name="downloads-ms" hostPath="/home/richard/Downloads/ms" writable="true" autoMount="true"/>
        </SharedFolders>
        <Clipboard mode="Bidirectional"/>
        <DragAndDrop mode="Bidirectional"/>
        <GuestProperties>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxControl.exe" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377846816000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxCredProv.dll" value="-" timestamp="1491668377861259000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxDisp.dll" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377851968000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGINA.dll" value="-" timestamp="1491668377861016000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGuest.sys" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377863502000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxHook.dll" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377851023000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMRXNP.dll" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377860685000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMouse.sys" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377864110000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGL.dll" value="4.1.14r77440" timestamp="1451577933139448000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLarrayspu.dll" value="4.1.14r77440" timestamp="1451577933136024000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLcrutil.dll" value="4.1.14r77440" timestamp="1451577933136618000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLerrorspu.dll" value="4.1.14r77440" timestamp="1451577933137228000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLfeedbackspu.dll" value="4.1.14r77440" timestamp="1451577933138889000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpackspu.dll" value="4.1.14r77440" timestamp="1451577933137787000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpassthroughspu.dll" value="4.1.14r77440" timestamp="1451577933138349000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxSF.sys" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377864792000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxService.exe" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377856704000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxTray.exe" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377856199000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxVideo.sys" value="5.0.34r113845" timestamp="1491668377865206000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/HostVerLastChecked" value="5.0.36" timestamp="1491668395740306000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/InstallDir" value="C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox Guest Additions" timestamp="1491668377838099000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision" value="113845" timestamp="1491668377837516000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-interval" value="10000" timestamp="1462047418972700000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-min-adjust" value="100" timestamp="1462016524553445000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-on-restore" value="1" timestamp="1462016530985333000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-start" value="1" timestamp="1462020738520954000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold" value="60000" timestamp="1462047479700617000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/TimesyncInterval" value="10000" timestamp="1462015496352195000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/TimesyncMinAdjust" value="100" timestamp="1462015535544402000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/TimesyncSetOnRestore" value="1" timestamp="1462015610228046000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/TimesyncSetStart" value="1" timestamp="1462015597821119000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/TimesyncSetThreshold" value="60000" timestamp="1462015569515855000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version" value="5.0.34" timestamp="1491668377836932000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt" value="5.0.34" timestamp="1491668377837203000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product" value="Windows 7" timestamp="1491668377834663000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release" value="6.1.7601" timestamp="1491668377835121000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/ServicePack" value="1" timestamp="1491668377836508000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1491669445323601000" flags=""/>
        </GuestProperties>
      </Hardware>
      <StorageControllers>
        <StorageController name="IDE Controller" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
          <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
            <Image uuid="{d1114527-c7b4-477d-a17f-4d094b170913}"/>
          </AttachedDevice>
          <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0">
            <Image uuid="{6352eeaa-3967-4db7-8901-60e6e44e61d8}"/>
          </AttachedDevice>
        </StorageController>
        <StorageController name="SATA Controller" type="AHCI" PortCount="1" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
          <AttachedDevice nonrotational="true" discard="true" type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
            <Image uuid="{e837b0b1-5453-4dec-9662-42cdc7afbe81}"/>
          </AttachedDevice>
        </StorageController>
      </StorageControllers>
    </Snapshot>
    <Hardware>
      <CPU>
        <PAE enabled="true"/>
        <LongMode enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="128"/>
      <Paravirt provider="Default"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false"/>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="1" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="2" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="3" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="4" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="5" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="6" type="Am79C973"/>
        <Adapter slot="7" type="Am79C973"/>
      </Network>
      <LPT>
        <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="7"/>
      </LPT>
      <AudioAdapter driver="Pulse" enabled="true"/>
    </Hardware>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that this is possible, but not easy; The GUI on virtual box does not want you to do this.

First **back everything up**. Then if you are feeling brave continue reading. I have not included every detail, and it is from memory. I did it about an hour ago, and it took a few hour to get it done. You will need to know how to edit xml, understand directed graphs, and have some knowledge of virtualbox.

I learnt that you can attach a snapshot image to a new virtual machine. This can be used to give you a machine with your latest snapshot. More on restoring all snapshots later.

### Attaching disk differences (disk snapshots)

To attach a snapshot, some loop jumping was needed, as the gui does not want you to do it.

First use the file date to guess with snapshot is which. While making notes —  try to attach the latest snapshot. You will get an error, telling you that you cannot, because another image is not known about (this is the parent). Now try to attach this. Keep at this until you find the base image, and repeat for any other snapshots (other branches). You will now have, in your notes, a directed graph of all of the snapshots.

Now create a new dummy VM, use this to attach the images, starting at the base and working towards the leafs. As you do this you should see in the virtual media manager, this directed graph appearing.

### Now to make the new VM

- Create a new VM, attached to the base image, and configure it.
- Virtual box will create a new differencing image (disk snapshot).
- repeat:

  - shutdown virtualbox manager, and hack the xml in the `.vbox` file, to point to the correct snapshot (instead of the new one).
  - restart vbox manager, and create a snapshot
- tidy up: by removing and snapshots that this process made.